# Confusing name of Git branch: Upstream or Downstream?

Tags: git, version-control, merge

In [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) you can see:

> Checking out a local branch from a remote-tracking branch
>   automatically creates what is called a `tracking branch` (and the
>   branch it tracks is called an ***upstream branch***). Tracking branches
>   are local branches that have a direct relationship to a remote branch.
>   If you’re on a tracking branch and type git pull, Git automatically
>   knows which server to fetch from and branch to merge into.

So Git knows it has directly merge from another branch **into** `tracking branch` and it seems better to name these branches as ***downstream*** branches instead of ***upstream***. But why they are named as ***upstream***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me but I *think* this is the source of your confusion:

> So Git knows it has directly merge from another branch **into** `tracking branch` ...

This is wrong.  That's not what a remote-tracking branch is and does.

First, let's make a note of how git references work.  Regardless of the actual reference (branch name, tag name, `refs/stash` for the `git stash` command, or whatever), a *reference*, in git, is simply a name that resolves to a hash, such as `0f90a088a1161e812e7cf9ef9724f9bfcb4267ec`.  Most (though not all) references have a full name that starts with `refs/`.  (Some references are *indirect* or *symbolic*, meaning they contain the name of another reference.  The special `HEAD` reference—this is one of the few that does not start with `refs/`—is normally symbolic as it normally contains the *name of the current branch*.  A symbolic reference must eventually resolve to a regular reference, which must in turn resolve to one of those SHA-1 hash values, with one special exception for what git calls an *unborn branch*, which I won't address here.)

Next, let's define the term "remote-tracking branch":  A *remote-tracking branch*, in git, is simply any reference whose full name begins with `refs/remotes/`.  Similarly, a (regular, ordinary, not-remote-tracking) branch<sup>1</sup> is any reference whose full name begins with `refs/heads/` (and for completeness, a *tag* is any reference whose full name begin with `refs/tags/`).

Typically your (single) remote is named `origin`, since `git clone url` creates a remote named `origin`.  This means your local git repository has `origin/master` as one of its remote-tracking branches.  The full name of `origin/master` is actually `refs/remotes/origin/master`, which—by definition—makes it a remote-tracking branch.

The initial `git clone url` does one other thing that you normally never need to adjust, but is useful to know because it is how remote-tracking branches are actually implemented.  The `git clone` sets up the *fetch refspecs* for `origin`, which you can see with:

```
git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch
```

The output from this command will read:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Note that on the left hand side of the colon (`:`) character, we see `refs/heads/*`.  These name (regular, ordinary, local) branches; the `*` part matches everything, so this means *every branch as seen on the remote*.  On the right, we see `refs/remotes/origin/*`.  These name remote-tracking branches—specifically, our own remote-tracking branches for the remote named `origin`.  The `*` in this case is replaced with whatever our git matches when it's connected to `origin` during a `git fetch`.<sup>2</sup>  (For completeness, the `+` at the front sets the *force* flag, so that `git fetch` will always update the remote-tracking branch.)

What this means is that **whenever you fetch from the remote, your git makes your remote-tracking branches match their git's branches.**  It does so *not* by doing any merging, but simply by *copying whatever they have* and then creating or replacing the remote-tracking branch so that it *exactly matches what they have* at the time the `git fetch` runs.

This means that a remote-tracking branch is your git telling you "this is what I saw on the remote, the last time I checked."

This is also *why* we can call the remote an "upstream".  Suppose, for instance, that remote `origin` refers to the official github repository for some project.  You clone the project to a local repository (not even another github fork, just a regular git repository on your local machine) and maybe make a few changes.  Then, after some time, you may decide to find out what's happened in the official repository since you cloned.  You need only run `git fetch origin` to pick up their changes.  If they have changed their `master` branch, you will immediately and automatically see these changes in your `origin/master` remote-tracking branch.

Since your work is derived from their work, your code is "downstream" of theirs, and theirs is "upstream" of yours.  Once you have fetched their new work, it's up to you how, or even whether, to modify your earlier changes to use their new version.  You can merge their new work, rebase onto their new work, ignore their work, or do whatever you like—but as long as your  work is based on theirs, they are "upstream" of you and you are "downstream" of them.

If your local branch—whatever its name is, `master` or some other name—has one of your remote-tracking branches set as its "upstream" (with `git branch --set-upstream-to` or similar), your `git status` commands will, after you `git fetch`, tell you about commits you have that they don't ("ahead 3") and commits they have that you don't ("behind 9").  You can then use `git merge` or `git rebase` to merge or rebase your changes with theirs, but this is *not* automatic, it's done *only when you tell your git to do it*.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>The term *branch* in git is actually ambiguous: it can mean either a *branch name*, which is that thing starting with `refs/heads/`, or it can refer to a portion of the commit graph.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452) for details.

<sup>2</sup>For some time, since git 1.8 or so, git also opportunistically updates remote-tracking branches on `git push` operations.  Specifically, if you run `git push remote ref` and the push successfully updates *`ref`* on *`remote`*, the push code also updates your remote-tracking branch for *`remote`*'s *`ref`*.  For example, after a successful `git push origin master`, your git knows where `origin/master` should point, so your git updates your copy of `origin/master`.

<sup>3</sup>If you run `git pull` instead of `git fetch`, know that `git pull` starts by doing `git fetch`, then running either `git merge` or `git rebase`.  This is meant as a convenience short-cut, since it's pretty common to *want* to merge or rebase and then remember at the last moment that you also need to `git fetch` first.  For beginners, though, I think it's much better to keep the two steps separate.